# SQL JOIN two tables based on periods

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables one has weeks and their start and end date. Second contains months with start and end dates.
I want them to be joined like on the picture.

[image: way how joined table should looks like]

I tried to use CASE WHEN in WHERE clause to achieve what I want but still have some troubles:
Here is my query:

```
SELECT * FROM TAB_A AS ref
INNER JOIN TAB_B AS in
ON ref.cal_id = in.cal_id
and (CASE WHEN
((MONTH(ref.end_date) > MONTH(in.start_date)) and (MONTH(ref.start_date) != MONTH(in.start_date)) and (MONTH(ref.end_date) = MONTH(in.end_date))) 
THEN (ref.end_date BETWEEN in.start_date AND in.end_date) 
ELSE (ref.start_date BETWEEN in.start_date AND in.end_date)
END)
```

And here is what I got from that query:

[image: output of the query]

With 2021W48 should be 2021M12 (not like my example 2021M11)

I tried different ways. Can you guys help me how to join those tables?

Regards,
Michal

Comment: what you ask is impossible and illogical. It might work with your example data here, because you only have 4 rows. But it will fail with a larger dataset of dates. You want to join week ranges with month ranges and expect to have a 1-1 relationship, but it cant be because weeks are crossing months.

Comment: So for example I need to expand those tables of days following one by one and join based on them, and deduplicate records after?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is `JOIN` on if the start date of the week is between the dates of the month. This is impossible to test, as images of data can't be used, however, perhaps this?

```sql
SELECT {Your Columns}
FROM dbo.WeeksTable WT
     JOIN dbo.MonthsTable MT ON WT.StartDate BETWEEN MT.StartDate AND MT.EndDate;
```

If it's based on the end date, use that:

```sql
SELECT {Your Columns}
FROM dbo.WeeksTable WT
     JOIN dbo.MonthsTable MT ON WT.EndDate BETWEEN MT.StartDate AND MT.EndDate;
```

Neither of these will reflect your expected results, as you allocate W39 to September, though it ends in October, and W48 to December though it starts in November; so there is a logic conflict here. If there is specific logic there, it needs to be explained.

Comment: This won't work for example your join will combine week 48 with month 11. But is should be week 48 with month 12

Comment: But the week starts in November, *not* December; why is it therefore joined to December?

Comment: And why is a week that starts in November and ends in December joined to December, but a week that start in September and ends in October joined to September? The logic is inconsistent here, @MichalK .

Comment: It is so consistent because it will be fiscal calendar so we shouldn't take into account standard weeks and months. In fiscal calendar years can have 13 months for example. @Larnu

Comment: That doesn't explain why it's allocated to a month it doesn't start in, @MichalK . If you can't explain that, the SQL Server can't implement it; it can't do logic you yourself don't understand.

Comment: I understand this logic :) you don't. E.g. Last week of January 2022 starts on Monday 31.01 and ends in 06.02. If my fiscal year starts at 3rd of January. I would like to have mentioned week as part of February. Then you'r join condition won't work

Comment: *"I understand this logic :) you don't."* And this is why ***you*** need to explain it... You aren't... If you understand the logic, *explain* it...

Comment: I just Explained, and I showed what I want to achieve. But I can agree with @Thomas G that it won't be possible until I won't add uniqe values to that tables which will allow me to create 1-1 relationship. But thought that I could find here any other solution

Comment: Where is your explanation then, @MichalK ? The last edit to your question was by someone else an hour ago, and you don't explain it in the comments, you just give an example. If it's based on the **end** date then why is W39 allocated to September?

Comment: It's 4-4-5 calendar meaning quarter has 3 month: first has 4 weeks, second 4 weeks, third 5 weeks And next quarter begins. Why are you picking on me that I don't understand logic instead of admit that you don't know how to achieve this or just saying that's imposible?

Comment: Anyway I achieved my goal using extra temp tables and procedures..